# Need a batch file to list out image files with dimensions

Tags: image, batch-file, filelist

I already have a batch file that displays the list of files in the folder ordered by file type:

```
dir /b /o:gen>filelisting.txt
```

I would like to make a .bat file that will also display the width and height of the images. does anyone have code that will do that or understands this type of programming better than i can?

Comment: This isn't something you can do with a simple batch file.  You need some other program to read the image information.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [tooltipInfo.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/tooltipInfo.bat) (jscript\bat hybrid that can be used as a `.bat`) that takes the tooptip information for a file and does not require any external software:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
    @echo off

    rem :: the first argument is the script name as it will be used for proper help message
    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*

    exit /b %errorlevel%

@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */

////// 
FSOObj = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var ARGS = WScript.Arguments;
if (ARGS.Length < 1 ) {
 WScript.Echo("No file passed");
 WScript.Quit(1);
}
var filename=ARGS.Item(0);
var objShell=new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
/////


//fso
ExistsItem = function (path) {
    return FSOObj.FolderExists(path)||FSOObj.FileExists(path);
}

getFullPath = function (path) {
    return FSOObj.GetAbsolutePathName(path);
}
//

//paths
getParent = function(path){
    var splitted=path.split("\\");
    var result="";
    for (var s=0;s<splitted.length-1;s++){
        if (s==0) {
            result=splitted[s];
        } else {
            result=result+"\\"+splitted[s];
        }
    }
    return result;
}


getName = function(path){
    var splitted=path.split("\\");
    return splitted[splitted.length-1];
}
//

function main(){
    if (!ExistsItem(filename)) {
        WScript.Echo(filename + " does not exist");
        WScript.Quit(2);
    }
    var fullFilename=getFullPath(filename);
    var namespace=getParent(fullFilename);
    var name=getName(fullFilename);
    var objFolder=objShell.NameSpace(namespace);
    var objItem=objFolder.ParseName(name);
    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787870(v=vs.85).aspx
    WScript.Echo(fullFilename + " : ");
    WScript.Echo(objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objItem,-1));

}

main();
```

Output if used against a picture:

```
C:\TEST.PNG :
Item type: PNG image
Dimensions: ?871 x 836?
Size: 63.8 KB
```

so you can:

```
for %%# in (*.jpg *.png *.tiff *.gif *.bmp) do (
    echo %%#
    for /f "delims=? tokens=2" %%a in ('toolTipInfo.bat "%%~#" ^|find "Dimensions:"')  do echo %%a
)
```

**OR**
 with [imgInfo.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/imgInfo.bat)

Answer (score 0):

Try saving this as xxx.bat;

```
Dim oDir: Set oDir = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
For Each oFile In oDir.Items
   wscript.echo oFile & " " & replace(oDir.GetDetailsOf(oFile,26), "x", "")
Next
```

Then from the command line:

```
cscript c:\xxx.vbs "C:\whatever\My Pictures"
```

For me, produces;

```
a926_thumb 180  180
abstract1 2197  1374
backscreen 1024  1024
burgin_small 207  205
```

Where the 1st number is width & the 2nd height.

Comment: for me it still only displays the files. i also had to save it as a vbs file instead of a bat file which was fine